# How to map ArrayList data to an DTO

Tags: java

As per the requirement, I have parsed an XML file and set data into these two DTO classes:

```
public class DetailsDTO implements java.io.Serializable {
private String      userid;
private String      accountnum;
private Customer    customer;
// setters and getters

public class Customer implements Serializable
{
private String            street;
private String            country;
// setters and getters
```

After adding data of the `Customer` class to `DetailsDTO`, I added this `DetailsDTO` to an `ArrayList` as shown:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
// and added these DetailsDTO class to an ArrayList
list.add(detailsDTO)
```

Now there is a Master DTO called as `WholeDetails` which consists of all variables defined in various DTO classes as shown.

```
class WholeDetails
{
private String   userid;
private String   accountnum;
private String   street;
private String   country;
}
```

Now, as you see, all the data is aviable within the `ArrayList`.

How can I extract the contents from `ArrayList` and map it to the `WholeDetails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do the mapping e.g.

```
List<DetailsDTO> list = new ArrayList<DetailsDTO>();    
// and added these DetailsDTO class to an ArrayList   
list.add(detailsDTO);  

List<WholeDetails> wholeDTOList = new ArrayList<WholeDetails>();   
for(DetailsDTO dto:list){  
  WholeDetails whole = new WholeDetails();  
  whole.setUserid(dto.getUserid());  
  whole.setAccountNum(dto.getAccountNum());  
  whole.setStreet(dto.getCustomer().getStreet());  
  whole.setCountry(dto.getCustomer().getCountry());  
  wholeDTOList.add(whole);

}
```

If you like it to be more short you could create an adapter class that maps the `DetailsDTO` to the `WholeDetailsDTO` and add the result object to the list

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , you saved my sleepless night today .